# What happens to the IView.Load event on a Form?

Tags: c#, interface

I've just read a tutorial on Winforms MVP and have come across something that seems a bit strange to me.

Without going into too much detail, the author suggests you should have a base view interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IView
{
    event EventHandler Initialize;
    event EventHandler Load;
}
```

Then any views you create implement this interface.

However I'm a bit confused what happens when a Windows Form implements this interface as it already has it's own Load event and intellisense seems to indicate that I am provided a handler for the form event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IView
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += (s,e) => { }; // Signature: EventHandler Form.Load
    }
}
```

What happens to IView.Load in this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean what will happen? You have already implemented `Load` event in the `Form` class, so you only need to provide `Initialize` event. You can also read about: Explicit Interface Implementation

Comment: I thought there'd be some kind of conflict since there's two events called Load?

Comment: Oh, you mean you added second `Load` event. There will be no conflict. It is completely different event, but just with the same name (so it's good to mark this event with `new` keyword). When you do `Load +=` you will set this new event. If you want to use event from `Form` class, you need to call `base.Load +='. Add some breakpoints, and test it.